# Are 807 NodeJS modules really required to use Font Awesome?

Tags: php, node-js, laravel

We contracted a web developer to make a really simple 40 page website using PHP+Twig. They sent the site to me in a zip file and when I unzipped it, it took almost 45 minutes to unzip because it had more than 60,000 files in it. It turns out that the site was built with Laravel (which we didn't want at all). The really suspicious thing is that there is a node_modules folder with more than 807 NodeJS modules.

They claim that 807 nodejs modules were required because they used fontawesome.

There is a package.json file in the archive which shows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "mobile-menu": "^2.0.8"
}
```

My question is should it have 807 different nodejs modules in the `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 1):

The Font Awesome node package itself has no dependencies, as you can see on their NPM page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome

Those 807 dependencies in their code are due to something other than Font Awesome proper. Perhaps they used a helper package to integrate Font Awesome into the site, and the helper package is what came with so many dependencies? Or perhaps the dependencies came from their build system, or the front-end JS libraries they used, or another part of their site development?

<strike>As an aside, as far as I remember from NPM there's no point in packaging up the `node_modules` folder when you send something because you can automatically re-create it on the other end by running `npm install`. But I could be wrong about that.</strike> -> Never mind, there are [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository).